# Google Sign in not working from app downloaded from playstore

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin, android-app-signing, app-signing

1. Created an app which uses [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) to login to the app with google login
2. Created a keystore for to sign my app, as is described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)
3. Signed my app and uploaded into [Google Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trackourspends)

   - When I was asked if I want to opt-in for the `Google Play App Signing`, I agreed
4. If I try to login to my app (downloaded from the playstore), I'm getting an error `messsage: DEVELOPER_ERROR`, `error code: 10`

> Note1: my app does not use firebase
>
> Note2: if I install the apk directly into my device, the login seems to work

*I'm sure the problem has something to do with how the application is signed with Google Play App Signing but I'm not able to isolate the issue*

#### Update:

- Downloaded the `google-services.json` from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) and added it under `/android/app` and now the app works if I download it from the release management page and install it manually. Still doesn't work if I install it directly from the Google Play Store though.

Comment: Have you added your SHA1 key to firebase console configuration?

Comment: You need to add release key SHA-1 in firebase console for it

Comment: I'm not using firebase, is firebase use mandatory?

Comment: What backend are you using

Comment: theres no backend, its a simple application (ledger to keep track of expenses)

Comment: @Raghudevan: would you move your answer to an answer box proper, please? We discourage the merging of answers into question posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Solution:

- The problem was that while generating the `google-services.json`, the `App signing certificate` `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` needs to be provided; I was providing the `Upload certificate`'s `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` which is why it wouldn't work on production.
- In essence, in the [credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), you'll need to create a two oauth client ids for Android (one with the `App Signing certificate` and one with the `Upload certificate` and one oauth client id of type `web` and in while using `react-native-google-signin` you need to specify the `webClientId`.

Answer (score 15):

It is very simple, Go to play store account where you uploaded your signed APK. select your App, then go to the **Release Management section** then **App signing**.

Copy the SHA1 key of App Signing certificate.

Go to this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Click on  **CONFIGURE A PROJECT** button

select your App, select Android, App your app package name, then paste the SHA1 certificate

Then click Create. Thats it.

Now you can use google signin in your App

Comment: 2021 UPDATE: It's now Google Play Store -> Release Section -> Setup -> App Integrity

Comment: I wish I could give you more points. really helpful the way you explained. worked like a charm

Comment: If you are using firebase: Do not add the sha1 certificate in google console as the answer suggests, add it in firebase console instead.

Answer (score 2):

You added sha-1 key  for your app in debug mode and at that time you will be able to do google sign in  your app.
But as the app goes in production, it requires sha-1 key for production.
And that you need to add at firebase console.
You can check your firebase console and check for android app.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

The above commad helps to create sha-1 key for debug version.

You meed to provide you signed key-store file path for production sha-1.
 And this will be done with command

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

You just need to provide specific paths for keystore file for released apk.

Comment: Ok, but this is the issue of sha1 for production app.

Comment: you must provide google-service.json file in you android/app or android/app/src/debug, then there you must provide this info with production key-hash
 
{
          "client_id": "xyz_abc_pqr.......apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "package_name",
            "certificate_hash": "sha-1 key hash for production"
          }
        },

Comment: So, after adding the google-services.json, the app works if i download it from the release management page and install it manually using adb but it still does not work when downloaded from the app store @prince

Comment: According to documemtion od react-native-google-sign, you must have to make an app on console.firebase.google.com

Comment: Android guide in this module told to add google-service.json file in app, you can download that by followong steps given in https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In
Link.

Comment: I've already added the `google-services.json` to the `/android/app` directory

Comment: From where you download that file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158422/discussion-between-prince-and-raghudevan-shankar).

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday same problem occurred to me.

Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your fire[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLRV.png)base account. See the image for the better understanding