# Issue: Need login credentials for app review

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

I've been trying to publish an app now for almost a month now. But I always get a reject from Google that *credentials are required for app review*. I am using Google Sign In as the only log in method, I already described in the **App Access** module in Play console that all users need to sign in with their Google account.

**Edit:** I created a test Gmail account and provided instructions together with the password via the **App Access** module but still facing the same issue.

**P.S** Crazy thing is that all my other published apps are all using Google sign in and have never faced this issue before. This inconsistency from Google at times can be nervewrecking

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? We recently pushed an update which was rejected because of _"Need login credentials for app review"_ for no reason, even though our test login credentials have been there in _App Access_ for years and never any problems. Not using Google Sign In though, just regular user/password.

Comment: Did this issue resolved ?

Comment: @Venkatesh yes it did, I created another account from my mobile device, and ensured it doesn't contain any 2 factor authentication & submitted the details for review

Comment: I have similar issue did you resolve it ?

Comment: @Madhav yes, my comment above should assist you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a testing Google account, test it on your app and from Google Play Console provide them with credentials to this account with a note that describe that this account could be used as an account for Google Sign in.

Comment: This is what I did but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem potentially comes from signing certificate. Use the key for production, not the one that you used for development. You can find more here:
[Google Sign in not working from app downloaded from playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107297/google-sign-in-not-working-from-app-downloaded-from-playstore/54566104#54566104)