# I can't add my app to google play: Issue: Need login credentials for app review

Tags: java, android, flutter

I can't add my app to google play. it gives the following error but I added login credentials.

ERROR:

```
Issue: Need login credentials for app review
In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app. 

{If in-app content can’t be accessed after entering login credentials}We could not access in-app content due to app connection error.
```

[image]

here i hide my mail and password but normally i write

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Did you find a solution about your problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, i couldn't find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Problem potentially comes from signing certificate. Use the key for production, not the one that you used for development. You can find more here: [Google Sign in not working from app downloaded from playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107297/google-sign-in-not-working-from-app-downloaded-from-playstore/54566104#54566104)

Also, make sure that your privacy policy is globally accessible. I put mine on my website, you can try to do the same.

Also, feel free to screen record usage of application on your side, submit what you record to Youtube and provide link to the video together with your login instructions.

Additional option: you may submit an appeal on reviewer's decision and you will receive one on one support in form of email discussion. They are providing generic answers, I was under impression that they weren't reading at all what I wrote in previous email, but when you combine this support with a lot of digging you will hopefully find the solution.