# Google Play reviewer constantly fails to login

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I submitted new Android app on Google Play and it needs to pass review process. The application has login with Google form and it is only way to enter the application and to use its content. In dedicated field in Google Play, I provided login instructions with Google account details that I created for this purpose. But, for the second time, I am getting rejection with message ***Issue: Need login credentials for app review***. I tried to login to app with provided account and I had no problems. Also, all security checks are turned off for this Google account (i.e. there is no ***Verify it is you procedure***). Can someone explain to me what additional details do I need to provide, what am I missing? I am attaching here the screenshot provided by reviewer, from which I don't understandwhat is the problem. Thanks[image]

Comment: i have the same problem, do you know how it got resolved?

Comment: Problem potentially comes from signing certificate. Use the key for production, not the one that you used for development. You can find more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107297/google-sign-in-not-working-from-app-downloaded-from-playstore/54566104#54566104